# Automatically save canvas png to local file system

Tags: javascript, html, desktop-application, filesystem-access

I am a web developer and I have never built anything for Desktop.
I am working on a new project where I'm doing some canvas rendering in real time. It works just fine in low-res but I want to do it in high-res and save every frame as a PNG file on my harddrive.

The problem is of course access to the local file system. 
So I was wondering what's the easiest way of doing this?

Do I have to create a desktop app with some framework like AppJS,Electron? What is the easiest way?

I only want to do this once and just on my PC.

Comment: App JS is a better choice imo.

Comment: Another alternative that you may find acceptable is to create a single video and then allow _that_ to be downloaded. I imagine it may be unsuitable, but felt it worth mentioning. Here's an article that discusses the technique: http://techslides.com/convert-images-to-video-with-javascript

Comment: I haven't thought about that, I'll have a look into it!